# Как сохранить настройки GUI windbg preview setting?

Tags: windbg

Набрал линейку быстрого доступа:

[image: screen]

сохранил workspace. Закрываю дебагер ,открываю его вновь. Линейка есть , но она пустая.

[image: screen]